# How to create dynamic two relational dropdown in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am new to [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js). I'm stuck trying to dynamically set the options of one select based on the selected value in another.

For example, I have two dropdowns named division and district.

```
var A = [{1: 'a'},{2:'b'}];
```

If value of A is 1, then the district select should load the related codes. I can do it with `jQuery` but not with Vue.

Here is my template.

```
<div class="form-group" :class="class_obj">
  <select name="div_code" v-model="div_code" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="">Choose One</option>
    <option v-for="option in div_list" v-bind:value="option.value">
      {{ option.text }}
     </option>
   </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group" :class="class_label">
    <label for="">District</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group" :class="class_obj">
     <select name="dist_code" v-model="dist_code" class="form-control" required>
       <option value="">Choose One</option>
     </select>
    </div>
```

Here is my javascript.

```
export default {
   data():{
     div_list: [
       {'1': "ABC"} , {'2': "DEF"}
     ];
   }
}
```

How can I load the dist_code select with related data from ajax when div_code value is 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle a change event on the `div_code` change

```
<select name="div_code" 
        v-model="div_code" 
        @change="onDivCodeChange"
        class="form-control" 
        required>
  <option value="">Choose One</option>
  <option v-for="option in div_list" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</select>
```

And add the `onDivCodeChange` method to your Vue.

```
methods:{
  onCodeChange(){
    // make an ajax call and set the options for your
    // dist_code here. For example:
    $.ajax({
      url: "...",
      data: {div_code: this.div_code},
      success: codes => this.code_list = codes
      error: err => console.log(err)
    })
  }
}
```

And of course add `code_list` as a property of your data and update your template.

```
<select name="dist_code" v-model="dist_code" class="form-control" required>
  <option value="">Choose One</option>
  <option v-for="code in code_list" :value="code.value">{{code.text}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: well, this explains better than my answer :)

Comment: @serkandemirel0420 Its all good :) If *all* the options were already available, a computed property would be a good choice.

Comment: Which ajax method you prefered in vue.js jQuery axax or vue-resource? I having trouble using vue-resource. Sometimes respone json return string and sometimes return array

Comment: @alien personally I prefer `axios`. But really, any of them is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

Create computed property.  Basically, when data property changes(should be used in computed property) the computed property will  update itself.

As in below example, when message property changes the reverseMessage will update itself.

```
<div id="example">
  <p>Original message: "{{ message }}"</p>
  <p>Computed reversed message: "{{ reversedMessage }}"</p>
</div>

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello'
  },
  computed: {
    // a computed getter
    reversedMessage: function () {
      // `this` points to the vm instance
      return this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
    }
  }
})
```

1- In your example, bind your first dropdown value to a data property.

2 -Create a computed property for the second dropdown and use the data
property in it.

3 -Write the template of it.

Done.

When the first dropdown changes the second dropdown will update itself.

Note: Vue documentation advise to use Watcher for Ajax requests instead of computed properties. Both are very similar.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers